# persian keyboard layout not present in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: keyboard, customization, input-language

i recently changed from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.10. now when i try to add persian keyboard layout it's not in the add an input source menu. i searched for persian and farsi and no languages were found. every other language seems to be there.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is EoL and off-topic. It was a really bad idea to upgrade to an unsupported release. It is unclear how you cold do it.

Comment: @user68186 idk why i typed 20.10, i meant 22.10. sorry.

Comment: @user68186 setting>Keyboard>Input sources..

Comment: Yes, Persian is there. If you edit your question and show us **exactly** which steps you took when looking for it, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's extremely weird but I found the Persian keyboard under Azerbaijani (Iran, Islamic Republic of)

Comment: Why should the name of the independent country of Iran come under another country? The persian is the official language of Iran! I really expect Ubuntu support to take care of this issue quickly